# Which "assumptions" made about the state space are Russell and Norvig referring to in their book?

Tags: terminology, search, norvig-russell, state-spaces

I am reading the cornerstone book, "Artificial Intelligence, A Modern Approach" by Stuart Russel, and Peter Norvig, and there is a passage in the book on page 98:

> The complexity results depend very strongly on the assumptions made
> about the state space. The simplest model studied is a state space
> that has a single goal and is essentially a tree with reversible
> actions. (The 8-puzzle satisfies the first and third of these
> assumptions.)

What are the "assumptions" in that context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The complexity results depend very strongly on the assumptions made about the state space. The simplest model studied is a state space that has a single goal and is essentially a tree with reversible actions.

The assumptions are the following:

1. > The simplest model studied is a state space
2. > that has a single goal
3. > and is essentially a tree with reversible actions.